# How to install certain dependencies in package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to optimize my CI build step. I want to install certain dependencies  before installing others. How can I achieve that?

For example, suppose my `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "krismath",
  "dependencies": {
    "lib-a": "^1.5.13",
    "lib-b": "^0.7.2",
    "lib-c": "^15.0.61"
}
```

I want to install `lib-b` first in order to use it in other build steps. If I do

```
npm install lib-b
```

this doesn't guarantee that the version of `lib-b` will be semantically compatible with the one in `package.json`.

Comment: using `caret` sign with version numbers is the most safe option for installing node packages. by running `npm install lib-b`, npm will install the newest backward compatible version of this package so you don't need to worry. If you need exact the same version in your package.json then just remove the `caret` : `"lib-b": "^0.7.2"` > `"lib-b": "0.7.2"` or run: `npm install lib-b@0.7.2` to install your exact desired version.

Comment: Oh! So when I run `npm install lib-b`, it will actually look inside the `package.json` for the semantically compatible version? (And does not install the actual latest version?)

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what `package.json` is responsible for.

Comment: That's news to me! I thought that `package.json` is only responsible for `npm install` and not individual installs. Can you please make it an answer so I can accept it?